# Подгрузка контента после нажатия

Tags: javascript

Привет,помогите,пожалуйста сделать такую штуку:
нажимаешь на кнопку загружается контент,пусть будут строки обычные,нажимаешь опять и еще выводиться,только если кнопку нажмешь она пропадает.Ну и появляется уже внизу).Ну или примерчик или статью подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [пример](http://www.simplecoding.org/javascript-vidzhet-beskonechnaya-zagruzka-tvitov.html), где происходит подгрузка твитов при помощи AJAX, но не по нажатию на кнопку, а при скроллинге.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит почитать об [`ajax`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/42426/). Удобнее всего использовать методы [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) и [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).